# setAudioStreamType is deprecated, how can I replace it?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to make a radio streaming app in Android Studio using MediaPlayer, but when I compile it shows the next error:

> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation
> for details.

I searched in Android documentation and I should replace this method for `setAudioAttributes`, how can I change it?

```
public class Radio extends Fragment {

    Button play_pause;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio, container, false);
        play_pause = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnplay);
        try {
               mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mp.setDataSource("http://198.27.83.65:9962/;stream.mp3");
                mp.prepareAsync();
         }
         catch (Exception e){
             Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error" + e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
         //mp = MediaPlayer.create(this.getContext(), R.raw.radio);
            play_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                         if(mp.isPlaying()) {
                            mp.pause();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Stop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            mp.start();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Start",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                }
            });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 50):

```
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

to

```
mp.setAudioAttributes(
            new AudioAttributes
               .Builder()
               .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
               .build());
```

`setAudioStreamType` was deprecated in API Level 26, you have to use new method `setAudioAttributes`

According to document:
`You must call this method before prepare() or prepareAsync() in order for the audio attributes to become effective thereafter.`

Comment: In my case, this replacement did not work as expected. I need the deprecated method in order to change the volume when forcing audio to play via ear piece. When using AudioAttibutes.Builder()..., the volume cannot be changed via the hardware buttons.

Comment: What about AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL? Can it be replaced with                           AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH?

Comment: can we use the same method below `API 26` or it is ok to use the same for all versions??

Comment: @VivekThummar you can't use the new method under API 26. But is it still a matter in 2021, since Google asks "New apps and app updates must target Android 10 (API level 29) or higher"

Answer (score 1):

Use **setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes)** instead of **setAudioStreamType()**

The Google Documentation says:

*Sets the audio stream type for this MediaPlayer. See AudioManager for a list of stream types. Must call this method before prepare() or prepareAsync() in order for the target stream type to become effective thereafter.*

Answer (score 1):

***setAudioStreamType*** has been replaced by ***setAudioAttributes***.
Below is the sample implementation for the same. For more understanding you can refer to the following doc :

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#kotlin

```
val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer().apply {
setAudioAttributes(
    AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
        .build()
)
setDataSource(applicationContext, myUri)
prepare()
start()
}
```