# setAudioStreamType deprecated need a replacement for Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to implement a media player that receives the media via a url, and to do that inside of a list.

So this is the code that google suggests:

```
        val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer().apply {
            setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
            setDataSource(url)
            prepare() // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
            start()
```

Except setAudioStreamType is deprecated.
I've seen a solution for this using java [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56744911/setaudiostreamtype-deprecated-method-how-i-can-replace-it) however I am using steam and the build method is private, not sure how to bypass this.

Comment: `build()` is not private in `AudioAttributes.Builder`. Post your code with that solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setAudioStreamType deprecated method, how i can replace it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56744911/setaudiostreamtype-deprecated-method-how-i-can-replace-it)